# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'passwcController' defined in file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am not sure what is wrong with my codes. I was trying to learn Spring Boot. But I am not able to run the application as i get the below error

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'passwcController' defined in file [D:\ProjStpring+Java\passwcontroller\target\classes\com\projects\passwcontroller\web\PasswcController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'passwcRepository' defined in com.projects.passwcontroller.data.PasswcRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.projects.passwcontroller.Passwc
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at com.projects.passwcontroller.PasswcontrollerApplication.main(PasswcontrollerApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'passwcRepository' defined in com.projects.passwcontroller.data.PasswcRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.projects.passwcontroller.Passwc
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.projects.passwcontroller.Passwc
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:583) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:75) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:233) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:182) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:165) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:325) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:231) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxpwt.png)

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.projects</groupId>
    <artifactId>passwcontroller</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>passwcontroller</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.4</version>
                </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>10.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.23</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>18</source>
                    <target>18</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

main.java.com.projects.passwcontroller.PasswcontrollerApplication.

```
package com.projects.passwcontroller;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PasswcontrollerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PasswcontrollerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

main.java.com.projects.passwcontroller.data.PasswcRepository

```
    package com.projects.passwcontroller.data;

import com.projects.passwcontroller.Passwc;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface PasswcRepository extends JpaRepository<Passwc, Long> {
    List<Passwc> findPasswd(long max, int count);

    Passwc findOne(long id);
}
```

main.java.com.projects.passwcontroller.web.PasswcController

```
 package com.projects.passwcontroller.web;

import com.projects.passwcontroller.Passwc;
import com.projects.passwcontroller.data.PasswcRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import java.util.List;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/passwds")
public class PasswcController {

    private PasswcRepository passwcRepository;

    @Autowired
    public PasswcController(PasswcRepository passwcRepository) {
        this.passwcRepository = passwcRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Passwc> passwds(
            @RequestParam(value = "max", defaultValue = Long.MAX_VALUE + "") long max,
            @RequestParam(value = "count", defaultValue = "20") int count) {
        return passwcRepository.findPasswd(max, count);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{passwdId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String passwd(@PathVariable("passwdId") long passwdId, Model model){
        model.addAttribute(passwcRepository.findOne(passwdId));
        return "passwd";
    }
}
```

main.java.com.projects.passwcontroller.Passwc

```
    package com.projects.passwcontroller;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.HashCodeBuilder;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import java.util.Date;

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.projects.passwcontroller.data.PasswcRepository")
public class Passwc {
    private final Long id;
    private String name;
    private final String passwd;
    private final Date date;

    public Passwc(String name, String passwd) {
        this.id = null;
        this.name = name;
        this.passwd = passwd;
        this.date = new Date();
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPasswd() {
        return passwd;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, obj, "id", "date");
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this, "id", "time");
    }
}
```

test.java.com.projects.passwcontroller.web.PasswcControllerTest

```
    package com.projects.passwcontroller.web;

import com.projects.passwcontroller.Passwc;
import com.projects.passwcontroller.data.PasswcRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItems;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.model;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.view;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup;


public class PasswcControllerTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldShowRecentPasswds() throws Exception {
        List<Passwc> expectedPasswd = createPassList(20);

        PasswcRepository mockRepository = mock(PasswcRepository.class);
        when(mockRepository.findPasswd(Long.MAX_VALUE, 20))
                .thenReturn(expectedPasswd);

        PasswcController controller = new PasswcController(mockRepository);

        MockMvc mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller)
                .setSingleView(
                        new InternalResourceView("/WEB-INF/views/passwds.jsp"))
                .build();

        mockMvc.perform(get("/passwds"))
                .andExpect(view().name("passwds"))
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("passwdList"))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("passwdList",
                        hasItems(expectedPasswd.toArray())));
    }

    private List<Passwc> createPassList(int count){
        List<Passwc> passwds = new ArrayList<Passwc>();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            passwds.add(new Passwc("GitHub", "new pass " + i));
        }
        return passwds;
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldShowPagedPasswds() throws Exception{
        List<Passwc> expectedPasswds = createPassList(50);

        PasswcRepository mockRepository = mock(PasswcRepository.class);
        when(mockRepository.findPasswd(238900, 50))
                .thenReturn(expectedPasswds);

        PasswcController controller = new PasswcController(mockRepository);

        MockMvc mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller)
                .setSingleView(
                        new InternalResourceView("/WEB-INF/views/passwds.jsp"))
                .build();

        mockMvc.perform(get("/passwds?max=238900&count=50"))
                .andExpect(view().name("passwds"))
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("passwdList"))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("passwdList",
                        hasItems(expectedPasswds.toArray())));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPasswd() throws Exception{
        Passwc expectedPasswd = new Passwc("Googel", "Qwerty123");

        PasswcRepository mockRepository = mock(PasswcRepository.class);
        when(mockRepository.findOne(12345))
                .thenReturn(expectedPasswd);

        PasswcController controller = new PasswcController(mockRepository);

        MockMvc mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller).build();

        mockMvc.perform(get("/passwds/12345"))
                .andExpect(view().name("passwd"))
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("passwd"))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("passwd", expectedPasswd));
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your main class located? Can you please add it as well?

Comment: must extend JpaRepository your repository interface and remove @Repository annotation it doesn't necessary.

Comment: @debugmode I already tried extending JpaRepository but nothing changed.

Comment: @JoãoDias I added a main class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might need to add a dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
   <version>2.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This also means you might be missing a couple of JPA annotations in `Passwc`. Take a look at https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa.

Comment: This helped, but now I get a new error, if I understand correctly it's because I do not have the database connected, right?


`Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
 If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
 If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).`

Comment: Now you need to have a database running. You can have an embedded one which is simpler to use. Take a look at https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa#using-spring-boot.

Comment: I did everything as in the example you sent me, but now I have a new error.
`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'passwcController' defined in file [D:\ProjStpring+Java\passwcontroller\target\classes\com\projects\passwcontroller\web\PasswcController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;`
If I understand correctly it is the same error as before.

Comment: This is a continuation of the error.
`nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'passwcRepository' defined in com.projects.passwcontroller.data.PasswcRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.projects.passwcontroller.Passwc`

Comment: Either create a new question or add the changes you did and the errors you are now getting to this one. Thanks!

Comment: I`m changed it.

Comment: Move `@EnableJpaRepositories` to your main class and make `Passwc` a JPA entity. Check this article --> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/spring-data-jpa.